# Поменять состояние button в реальном времени

Tags: python, tkinter

Необходимо поменять состояние кнопки, когда пользователь заполнить полня логина и пароля. Как проверять состояние кнопки? бесконечным циклом?

```
auth = Tk()
auth_frame = ttk.Frame(auth, padding='10 10 10 10')
auth_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nwes')
auth_frame.columnconfigure(0, minsiz=100)
U_lgn, U_pwd = StringVar(), StringVar()
ttk.Label(auth_frame, text='Login').grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10)
x = ttk.Entry(auth_frame, textvariable=U_lgn)
x.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='we', pady=10)
ttk.Label(auth_frame, text='Password').grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)
y = ttk.Entry(auth_frame, textvariable=U_pwd)
y.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='we', pady=10)
but_con = ttk.Button(auth_frame, text="Connect", state='disabled')
but_con.grid(row=2, sticky="we", pady=10, columnspan=2)
if U_lgn.get() and U_pwd.get(): but_con.config(state='active')
# auth.destroy()
x.focus()
auth.mainloop()
```

Comment: @insolor а как правильно привязаться к событию?

Comment: @insolor     `while not (U_lgn.get() and U_pwd.get()):
        pass
    else:
        but_con.configure(state='normal')` Так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить слежение за состоянием переменных, привязанных к текстовым полям:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

auth = Tk()

auth_frame = ttk.Frame(auth, padding='10 10 10 10')
auth_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nwes')
auth_frame.columnconfigure(0, minsiz=100)

var_login, var_password = StringVar(), StringVar()

ttk.Label(auth_frame, text='Login').grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10)
entry_login = ttk.Entry(auth_frame, textvariable=var_login)
entry_login.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='we', pady=10)

ttk.Label(auth_frame, text='Password').grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)
entry_password = ttk.Entry(auth_frame, textvariable=var_password)
entry_password.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='we', pady=10)

but_con = ttk.Button(auth_frame, text="Connect", state='disabled')
but_con.grid(row=2, sticky="we", pady=10, columnspan=2)


def callback(*args):
    if var_login.get() and var_password.get():
        # Если оба поля заполнены, делаем кнопку активной
        but_con.config(state='active')
    else:
        # Если одно из полей не заполнено
        # (были заполнены, а потом пользователь очистил одно из них) 
        # - делаем кнопку неактивной
        but_con.config(state='disabled')


# Добавляем слежение за состоянием переменных, при записи в них будет вызываться функция callback
var_login.trace_add("write", callback)
var_password.trace_add("write", callback)

entry_login.focus()

auth.mainloop()
```

Альтернативный вариант - делаем периодическую проверку состояния полей (будет видна небольшая задержка перед изменением состояния кнопки, даже если уменьшить интервал проверки):

```
...

def timer_func(*args):
    if var_login.get() and var_password.get():
        but_con.config(state='active')
    else:
        but_con.config(state='disabled')

    # Планируем следующий запуск функции через 100 миллисекунд
    auth.after(100, timer_func)


timer_func()

entry_login.focus()

auth.mainloop()
```

Использовать просто бесконечный цикл в основном потоке в оконных приложениях нельзя: если сделать это до вызова `auth.mainloop()` - то окно просто не появится, если в каком-нибудь обработчике событий - окно зависнет.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно `trace_add`. Правильно ли я понял, что `auth.after` из django?

Comment: Нет, метод `after` относится к объекту `Tk()`, django тут вообще ни при чем.